# Can I set up a proxy for everything but 1 program?

Tags: proxy

I want to prevent updates, telemetry, update notifications, internal Windows advertising. Block everything as if Windows was offline. But I want 1 browser to connect to the ethernet wired connection as if nothing was a miss. Or is it that Windows can find a way around the proxy to do undesired activities?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is essentially "Windows No Phone Home". Right?

That's not really what proxy servers are for. A firewall seems more appropriate for the task at hand. You basically need just 4 rules:

1. Allow DHCP in / out (if you don't use static IP addressing)
2. Allow DNS in / out
3. Allow [selected browser] all in/out
4. Deny all

Granted this is a simplified example; likely you'd need to allow some other traffic as well, at least in your internal network. For example a printer or a storage device in your internal network would be blocked on the same go.

A proxy could be also configured to do this kind of traffic filtering... but you'd be configuring the proxy to act as a of firewall anyway, which seems to me a tad complicated to fulfill a simple need. That's because proxy's role is not blocking traffic, it's forwarding traffic between your system and the inertnet.

I wanted to analyze Windows' incessant network connections. I didn't want to use Windows FW for it, because it's not easy to configure, and it's from Microsoft - it's designed to allow Windows to chat with them. I didn't want to install anything either, I wanted a portable tool, something I can unpack and run directly from the folder. After shopping around for a suitable freeware tool I found [Simplewall](https://www.henrypp.org/product/simplewall).

It has a clear interface, allow / deny rules are easy to distinguish; and it comes with a good ruleset out of the box. Shut down Win FW, and have nothing else running but your browser and Simplewall. Then move everything else but the browser, DHCP and DNS to the "not allowed to connect" -section in the firewall's GUI.

Now you start to teach it. When something tries to connect, it will give you an audible ping and a popup window. In the popup you see what exactly is connecting, and exactly where. You can allow or deny just by clicking a button - this will create an appropriate rule. You can create every rule as permanent or temporary (valid only until the next reboot).

Don't try this while you're trying to do productive work, seriously :-D In the beginning you'll be interrupted several times a minute - that's how often Windows connects. It will settle down pretty fast, tho. Once you have the ruleset that suits your needs, you can make them permanent and install Simplewall - if you want to.

To understand what exactly is happening you will need to do a bit of googling. That's because you don't see "Windows attempting to connect Microsoft" - you'll see "mfcdn attempting to connect 192.0.5.120". That might be your ACME Awesome Alliterator trying to download a critial update.

But then again there is no drop-in, set-and-forget -tool ready-made for this purpose, you will also need to study to get a proxy to do this. TANSTAAFL. To me it's easier to start blocking traffic with a tool that's created for the purpose (firewall) than with a tool designed for the opposite (proxy) :-)

Simplewall isn't the only available option. It's just the one I found to be suitable for my needs - YMMV.

Comment: This is my first time using Windows Defender Firewall Advanced Security. I don't use a static IP addressing. I don't know how or where to write the rules to allow DHCP, DNS, and my browser.

Comment: So you need 3 rules to start with :) I'm amending my answer a bit.